# STTY may have been deleted?

Tags: macos, terminal, stty

I was installing ruby/rails/gem and homebrew and got frustrated. I think I deleted the stty folder. ANYWAY, what can I do? It doesn't seem to have ever happened on the internet before.

Running stty comes back with command not found...

Answer (score 2):

The `stty` command can't be easily deleted; you'd have to be running with administrator privileges.  It is supposed to be located in `/bin/stty` (try `ls /bin/stty` to make sure it's still there).

My guess is that you altered your shell's `$PATH` variable (which is a colon-separated list of directories that the shell searches for commands when you run them only by name).

Try this to see your current path: `echo $PATH`.

Then make sure that `:/bin` appears somewhere in that value, e.g.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/bin
```

To fix this permanently, make sure that `PATH` is set in a shell startup file, e.g. `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Comment: I did check with ls. I get: 
ls: /bin/stty: No such file or directory

Comment: It's been deleted, then.  If you have Time Machine on, you can access your backup disk from the terminal (a disk under /Volumes) and look for a copy of the deleted files.  Or use the recovery partition to see if the files are there.  If those backups don't exist you may need to reinstall the OS to repair /bin.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the stty from a friends mac. It seems to be working fine. I have run a few commands and there have been no issues yet.